# ignoreWarnings having no effect with CRACO and webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, craco

I'm getting a compilation warning from an external module.  This is causing my build to fail, and its annoying:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@private_team/library/styles/css/min/beam.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/@private_team/library/styles/css/min/beam.min.css)
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Warning

> (1206:125827) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

I am working on a project that was initiated with create-react-app, and is now running react-scripts 5, which uses webpack 5 under the hood.  We are using [craco](https://github.com/dilanx/craco) to customize a few things, so I have access to add some customization to my webpack config.  My craco.config.js looks like this:

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".jsx", ".js"]
    },
    // the @private_team/library package was causing errors, which this fixed:
    alias: {
      "react/jsx-runtime": "react/jsx-runtime.js",
      "react/jsx-dev-runtime": "react/jsx-dev-runtime.js"
    },
    // this is what webpack says to add, but its not helping
    ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        message: /autoprefixer/
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      new NodePolyfillPlugin({
        excludeAliases: ["console"]
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
  ]
};
```

I'm trying to add `ignoreWarnings` in here, but no matter what variations I use, these warnings are still present in my console.  I've tried variations like:

```js
 ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        text: /flex/
      }
    ],

 ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        module: /node_modules/
      }
    ],

 ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        module: /.css&/
      }
    ],

 ignoreWarnings: [/autoprefixer/],
```

Seems like no matter what I try, the `ignoreWarnings` is not responding.  I know that the craco.config.js file is being read, as the `alias` property made a positive impact on some other issues I was having.

What is going wrong here?  Is this a craco issue?  A webpack issue?  How can I ignore these warnings properly?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I asked too soon.  The way to do this with CRACO is to add it to the `configure` property:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    ...,
    configure: {
      ignoreWarnings: [{ module: /.css$/ }]
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

I'll leave this here in the rare event that it might help someone else.

Comment: rare event happened, thank you very much

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore warnings from `node_modules`, add this to your `craco.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      ignoreWarnings: [{ module: /node_modules\// }],
    },
  },
};
```